# Can gulp watch only for addition/removal of files?

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

Example usage:

**Task**: Using `gulp-inject` to inject `js/**/*.js` files into index.html.

**Problem**: If I watch for changes in the `js/**/*.js` glob, this would mean that I'm running the inject task each time any of the `.js` files' content is changed, which is unnecessary, since the paths don't change.

**Question**: How can I create a watcher that would only watch for addition/removal of the files in the glob?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can give watch a callback function that gets the file object, including the type of event:

`add - file was added to watch or created
change - file was changed
unlink - file was deleted`

see https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch